# Ordering system (pizza)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i need help creating a pizza ordering system that allows the user to select size and toppings by checkboxes , quantity by a numeric up down and allows the user to enter the amount given by the customer in a textbox, the process is to add up all the values of the selected textboxes and together and multiply it by the quantity, it also calculates the change due to the customer, the output is to display the transactions(multiple) in a listbox(total price, amount given and change).

The problem is with regards to the checkboxes not adding up the correct values and when the calculate button is clicked and the values in the listbox are doubled after the 1st transaction.Here is my code:

```
    Public Class Form1
Dim small As Double = 25.75
Dim medium As Double = 69.46
Dim large As Double = 98.21
Dim extraCheese As Double = 5.12
Dim mushrooms As Double = 5.75
Dim blackOlives As Double = 5.25
Dim onions As Double = 4.0
Dim greenPepper As Double = 4.5
Dim tomatoes As Double = 4.25
Dim change As Double
Dim total As Double
Dim amountGiven As Double
Dim pizzaSize As Double
Dim pizzaToppings As Double


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    If (smallCheckbox.Checked) = True Then
        pizzaSize = pizzaSize + small
    End If
    If mediumCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaSize = pizzaSize + medium
    End If
    If largeCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaSize = pizzaSize + large
    End If
    If extraCheeseCheckbox.Checked = True Then

        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + extraCheese
    End If
    If mushroomsCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + mushrooms
    End If
    If blackOlivesCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + blackOlives
    End If
    If onionsCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + onions
    End If
    If greenPepperCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + greenPepper
    End If
    If tomatoesCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        pizzaToppings = pizzaToppings + tomatoes

    End If


    total = (pizzaSize + pizzaToppings) * NumericUpDown1.Value
    totalTextbox.Text = total

    amountGiven = TextBox2.Text
    change = amountGiven - total
    TextBox3.Text = change

    ListBox1.Items.Add("==========================================")

    If smallCheckbox.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Pizza size : Small")
    End If
    If mediumCheckbox.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Pizza size : Medium")
    End If
    If largeCheckbox.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Pizza size : Large")
    End If


    ListBox1.Items.Add("Quantity : " & NumericUpDown1.Value)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Total Cost : " & total.ToString )
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Amount Tendered : " & amountGiven)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Change : " & change)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("==========================================")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("                                          ")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("==========================================")

End Sub
```

If someone could please assist me it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific with how it malfunctions.  For example, include your inputs, expected output, and actual output (or errors).

Comment: You never initialize your variables before you start adding to them. This means that once you've input once and start a new order, the variables still contain the values from the end of the previous order.

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction variables are never reset to zero. Try this,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

pizzaSize = 0;
```